# Rails: searching across multiple models without associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an autocomplete form on my front-end; what I'd like to do is a search across multiple models, returning a mix of the results. All related posts that I have read are about models with associations. Here's a quick glance at a simplified version of my schema:

```
  create_table "countries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "iso"
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "cities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "country_code"
  end
```

I've tried a `join` between a `countries` `iso` and a `books` `country_code`, but that still leaves out `cities`. I've also tried this: `Book.where("name ILIKE ?", "%term%") + Country.where("name ILIKE ?", "%term%") + City.where("name ILIKE ?", "%term%")` but that returns an array not an ActiveRecord::Relation, therefore I can't use limit on it leading to larger than needed searches (only 5 results are needed for the autocomplete). How can I go about doing this? If it helps, I'm using PostgreSQL.

EDIT: I ended up using the pg_search gem and it seems to be working well!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is union.

Instead of using ActiveRecord, you should write it in MySQL (https://thepugautomatic.com/2014/08/union-with-active-record). If you still want to use ActiveRecord, you can use [active_record_union](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union) gem. Then change your code as below:

```
  Book.select('name').
    union(Country.select('name')).
    union(City.select('name')).
    where("name ILIKE ?", "%term%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with the above query with the following changes :

```
search_limit = 5

search_results = (Book.where("name ILIKE ?", "%term%").limit(search_limit) + 
                  Country.where("name ILIKE ?", "%term%").limit(search_limit) + 
                  City.where("name ILIKE ?", "%term%").limit(search_limit)
                  ).take(search_limit)
```

I'm using the `Array#take` method which achieves the same objective as `ActiveRecord::QueryMethod#limit` would.